# How to make an object accessible to other library

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've done a library in java and now I'm trying to make an interface for kotlin in another library.

JavaLib -> KotlinLib -> App

KotlinLib implements JavaLib and I make a mask in kotlin for the methods of the JavaLib.

In Java I have a model of an object enum that I need to used in the app.

```
public enum StoreProtectionLevel {
    ENCRYPTED,                              // Values stores in Keystore of Android
    ENCRYPTED_WITH_WEAK_AUTHENTICATION,     // Values using a weak authentication previously
    ENCRYPTED_WITH_STRONG_AUTHENTICATION    // Values using a strong authentication previously
}
```

If I use the JavaLib, I can import StoreProtectionLevel, but If I want to import this object from KotlinLib, the object is not accessible.

How I can do this object for the kotlinlib?

Comment: As you said `KotlinLib` implements `JavaLib` and `StoreProtectionLevel` enum is inside `JavaLib`. If `StoreProtectionLevel` is not inside of `KotlinLib`, how are you suppose to import it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to expose this object, or if I need to do another object  and a parser.

Comment: Declaring your `JavaLib` dependency in `KotlinLib` as API is one way of exposing transitive dependency to consumer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to not create an additional Kotlin library on top of your Java library because Kotlin can use Java code without problems (with some syntactic quirks sometimes).

What you should do is creating an additional companion library (optional) which adds extension functions to make life easier for Kotlin users.

Something like Jetpack project is doing with `-ktx` artifact for their Java libraries